# How to show the arrow icon always in Extjs Grid?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am Using Extjs Grid V6.2 the combo box in an editable grid and the combo box arrow icon can only show after I double clicked the field. So how can i easily get it shown at the very beginning, 
    (e.g.) When the grid shows.

```
{
                            editor: {
                                xtype: 'combobox',
                                queryMode: 'local',
                                displayField: 'name',
                                collapsible: true,
                                valueField:'abbr',
                                store: {
                                    Fields: ['abbr', 'name'],
                                    data: [{"abbr": "INR", "name": "INR"},
                                        {"abbr": "EUR", "name": "EUR"},
                                        {"abbr": "USD", "name": "USD"}],
                                },
                            },
                            dataIndex: 'currency',
                            flex: .5,
                            collapsible: true,                        
                        },
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `editor` use `widgetcolumn`

```
Ext.application({
name: 'Fiddle',

launch: function() {

   var grid =   Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        store: {
            Fields: ['abbr', 'name'],
            data: [{"abbr": "INR", "name": "INR"},
            {"abbr": "EUR", "name": "EUR"},
            {"abbr": "USD", "name": "USD"}],
        },
        columns: [{
            dataIndex: 'name',
            xtype: 'widgetcolumn',
            widget: {
                xtype: 'combo',
                store: ['INR', 'EUR', 'USD']
            }
        }]
    });
  }
});
```

[sencha fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/24bg)

Comment: I try this code.This is working.But the Problem is width and width hover size is not same.And also affected another  grid column width.How to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the screenshot of my issue, it shows a grid width changes.

[image: ScreenShot]